# How to solve this Error Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I am Trying to Solve this Error, which is encountered while building my application

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.DirectoryEntriesReader found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilder found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorBuilderImpl found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.FileVisitorImpl found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.LinkFollowing found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathNode found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$bfsIterator$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalk$dfsIterator$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathTreeWalkKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathWalkOption found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.optionals.OptionalsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
> Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.22) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)

**I tried solving this error while changing the version of my JDK and various other solutions provided on stack overflow but nothing worked, can someone solve it please..**

Comment: change your gradle version also when you are changed the jdk version because some time its issue is also occur due to that